# Omniauth-twitter Devise undefined method `stringify_keys' for [:email, :current_password]:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

Hello hopefully someone can help me with this.  I have been working on an application that allows obviously the user to sign up with either twitter or just a normal site sign up.  Everything seemed to be fine then all of a sudden I was unable to update a user.  It almost acts like it never actually determines whether a user requires a password or not.

Looked here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

following the modifications for Rails 4.

Followed this one for the omniauth part: http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised

Here is where the error happens per rails:

```
# doesn't know how to ignore it
  params[:user].delete(:current_password)
  @user.update_without_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update))
  # Rails 3: @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
end
```

but it always seems to go there, whether it's a local user or not. So like I said it acts like it's not determining whether the password is required or not.

[edit]

I'm sorry maybe I wasn't clear.  I followed the tuts to a T.  All the parts and pieces are there.

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
u.permit(:avatar, :firstname, :lastname, :mobile, :work, :city, :state, :zip, :email,        :password, :password_confirmation)
end
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
  u.permit(:avatar, :firstname, :lastname, :mobile, :work, :city, :state, :zip, :email,    :password, :password_confirmation)
end
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
home_path(resource)
end

end
```

registrations_controller.rb (shortened for brevity)

```
def update
@user = User.find(current_user.id)

successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
  @user.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update))
  # Rails 3:  @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
else
  # remove the virtual current_password attribute update_without_password
  # doesn't know how to ignore it
  params[:user].delete(:current_password)
  @user.update_without_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update))
  # Rails 3: @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
end

if successfully_updated
  set_flash_message :notice, :updated
  # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
  sign_in @user, :bypass => true
  redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
else
  render "edit"
end
end

def needs_password?(user, params)
user.email != params[:user][:email] ||
  params[:user][:password].present?
end
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:17:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:229:in `block in update' 
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in      with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.0.0)  lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in  transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0)  lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in  `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in   `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:228:in `update'
/home/jemmett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-    3.1.0/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:93:in `update_without_password'
app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:35:in `update'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in   `_run__181177902206041806__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in  process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in   `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in  `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'  
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'  
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:44:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0)    lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'  
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in    `_run__2437565407170691624__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/jemmett/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in  `service'
/home/jemmett/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in  `run'
/home/jemmett/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block    in start_thread'
```

maybe this will shed some more light?

Answer (score 2):

Change the following

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in)
```

To:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitizer(:sign_in)
```

Using devise_parameter_sanitizer.for will return an array but update user ask for a hash object

Comment: Nice I'll look at this when I get home tonight. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I believe it should be 'sanitize' not 'sanitizer'. See here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb#L20

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. it was working for me.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  before_filter :authenticate_student!
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit! }
    end




  end
```

Comment: But it was working for me. Maybe it something different happened with you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the following `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end
end
```

If you've done that and it still isn't working, make sure params[:user] is the hash you're expecting.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have that done already.  Like I said it worked, but out of the blue it quit. Nothing changed.

Comment: What line is the error occurring at?  Can you include the full stack trace?  Very difficult to troubleshoot without that info.

Comment: I can provide it later, unfortunately I'm not at that machine at the moment.